# Why my model not work in serviceRepository laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a service-providers here as well as http://dfg.gd/blog/decoupling-your-code-in-laravel-using-repositiories-and-services
My ServiceProvider:

```
class UsersRepositoryServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('App\Repositories\Users\UsersInterface', function($app)
        {

            return new UsersRepository(new User);

        });
    }
```

And i get error: `Call to a member function find() on a non-object` 
My Repository:

```
use \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
//..
protected $usersModel;

public function __consturct(Model $users)
{
    $this->usersModel = $users;
}

/**
 * Get user by id
 * 
 * @param mixed $userId
 * @return Model
 */
public function getUserById($userId)
{
    return $this->convertFormat($this->usersModel->find($userId));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

__consturct is misspelled.

correct is __construct